# Not a problem per se, but at what times does the gnome live wallpaper in 3.4 change?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I've been looking online for the location of the xml file that says how often the wallpaper changes and I can't find it, anyone know where it is? Or what time the wallpaper changes? It's really bugging me that I don't know :)

Comment: Look at the folders under `/usr/share/backgrounds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changing version of the standard gnome 3 wallpaper changes with the time of day. In the morning, it is light, and it gets darker over the day.

Like edwin said, you can find all of the wallpapers (the different light / dark versions of the gnome 3 wallpaper and all other standard wallpapers) in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`

**EDIT:** It seems that the standard wallpaper is more than just images changing at a special time. It is the only changing wallpaper in the standard configuration that uses transitions, at least in my gnome version (3.8). I could imagine that this isn't the case in 3.4, but at least some parts of the following should also apply to gnome 3.4:

The configuration files for the changing backgrounds are located in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/` and for the Adwaita standard theme it redirects to another config file: `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/adwaita-timed.xml`. You also find the three wallpapers between which the transition happens in the same folder as the config file.

Comment: I thought there was an xml file somewhere, not in directory you specified up above although the still wallpapers were.

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope this new information helps :)